# Given $e^{-5}\frac{5^n}{n!}=e^{-5}\frac{5^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},$ find the value of $n$

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I do not know how to find the value of $n$ this is a past paper question I am trying to solve, any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the expression in the title and add curly brackets to group exponents.

Comment: @CiaPan i edited it now thank you

Comment: Just mulitiply on both sides by $e^5(n+1)!/5^n$.

Comment: 'I don't know' is quite a general message, Most posts appear here because they authors do not know something. Please explain what you don't know. What do you understand from the problem and what you do not? What did you try to solve it?

Comment: After simplification, $(n+1)!=5n!$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply both sides by $\frac{e^5(n+1)!}{5^n}$ simplify and get

$$5=n+1\rightarrow n=4$$

---

> how do you know you must multiply both sides by...

I do not know. It is just a conclusion. To realize that you can rewrite you equation in the following way:

$$\frac{e^{-5}\cdot 5^n}{n!}=\frac{e^{-5}\cdot 5^n\cdot 5}{(n+1)\cdot n!}$$

As you can see, both sides contain

$$\frac{e^{-5}\cdot5^n}{n!}$$

thus this eliminates and it remains only

$$1=\frac{5}{n+1}$$

thus evidently, $n=4$

Comment: how do you know you must multiply both sides by $\frac{e^5(n+1)!}{5^n}$how did you get this number

Comment: @maryjames : see my edits

Comment: Thank you very much but i dont get the second step how does dividing bu $5^n$ eliminate the n! and the (n+1)!

Comment: @maryjames : I modified my edits trying to explain  you how to proceed in different words

Answer (score 2):

*A variant*: simplify the common factors:
$$\mathrm e^{-5}\frac{5^n}{n!}=\mathrm e^{-5}\frac{5^n\cdot 5}{n!\,(n+1)}\iff 1=\frac 5{n+1}\iff n+1=5.$$